# Java understanding I/O streams

Tags: java

I/O streams in Java are the most misunderstood concept for me in programming.

Suppose, we get input stream from a socket connection:

```
DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(clientSocket.getInputStream());
```

When I get data from a remote server, which of these describes things correctly?

1. Data stored in the `in` variable. When extra data comes from server, it appends to `in`, increasing its size. And then we can read data from `in` variable that way:

   ```
   byte[] messageByte = new byte[1000];
   boolean end = false;
   String dataString = "";
   while(!end)
   {
       bytesRead = in.read(messageByte);
       messageString += new String(messageByte, 0, bytesRead);
       if (messageString.length == 100)
       {
           end = true;
       }
   }
   ```
2. `in` is only a link to the source of data and doesn't contain data itself. When we call `in.read(messageByte)` 1000 bytes copy from the socket to `bytesRead`?

   Alternatively, instead of a socket let's say we have stream connected to file on HDD. When we call `in.read(messageByte)` we read 1000 bytes from HDD, yes?

Which approach is right? I tend to think it's #2, but if so where is data stored in the socket case? Is the remote server waiting when we read 1000 bytes, and then sends extra data again? Or is data from the server stored in some buffer in the operating system?

Comment: You can think of a stream here as a window to the physical source of the data.  It does not store the data itself but merely allows you to read it.

Comment: #2 is the correct situation. The data to be read is stored in the OS's buffer for the socket, until you request the data from the Java stream.

Comment: Have you read [The Java™ Tutorials - I/O Streams](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/streams.html)?

Comment: Yes, I read it. But answer of John Kugelman give me full understanding of this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on the type of stream. Where the data is stored varies from stream to stream. Some have internal storage, some read from other sources, and some do both.

- A `FileInputStream` reads from the file on disk when you request it to. The data is on disk, it's not in the stream.
- A socket's `InputStream` reads from the operating systems buffers. When packets arrive the operating system automatically reads them and buffers up a small amount of data (say, 64KB). Reading from the stream drains that OS buffer. If the buffer is empty because no packets have arrived, your `read` call blocks. If you don't drain the buffer fast enough and it gets full then the OS will drop network packets until you free up some space.
- A `ByteArrayOutputStream` has an internal `byte[]` array. When you write to the stream it stores your writes in that array. In this case the stream *does* have internal storage.
- A `BufferedInputStream` is tied to another input stream. When you `read` from a `BufferedInputStream` it will typically request a bug chunk of data from the underlying stream and store it in a buffer. Subsequent `read` requests you issue are then satisfied with data from the buffer rather than performing additional I/O on the underlying stream. The goal is to minimize the number of individual `read` requests the underlying stream receives by issuing a smaller number of bulk reads. In this case the stream has a mixed strategy of some internal storage and some external reads.

Answer (score 2):

> 1. Data stored in in variable.

No.

> When extra data comes from server, it appends to in, increase it size. And then we can read data from in variable that way:

```
byte[] messageByte = new byte[1000];
boolean end = false;
String dataString = "";
while(!end)
{
    bytesRead = in.read(messageByte);
    messageString += new String(messageByte, 0, bytesRead);
    if (messageString.length == 100)
    {
        end = true;
    }
}
```

No. See below.

> 2. `in` is only link to source of data, and don't contains data themselves.

Correct.

> And when we call `in.read(messageByte);` 1000 bytes copy from socket to bytesRead?

No. It blocks until:

- at least one byte has been transferred, or
- end of stream has occurred, or
- an exception has been thrown,

whichever occurs first. See the Javadoc.

> (Instead socket, we can have stream connected to file on HDD, and when we call in.read(messageByte) we read 1000 bytes from HDD. Yes?)

No. Same as above.

> What approach right?

Neither of them. The correct way to read from an input stream is to loop until you have all the data you're expecting, or EOS or an exception occurs. You can't rely on `read()` filling the buffer. If you need that, use `DataInputStream.readFully()`.

> I tend to 2

That doesn't make sense. You don't have the choice. (1) and (2) aren't programming paradigms, they are questions about how the stream actually works. The question of how to write the code is distinct from that.

> where data stored in socket?

Some of it is in the socket receive buffer in the kernel. Most of it hasn't arrived yet. None of it is 'in the socket'.

> Or remote server waiting when we read 1000 bytes, and then send extra data again?

No. The server sends through its socket send buffer into your socket receive buffer. Your reads and the server's writes are very decoupled from each other.

> Or data from server stored in any buffer in operating system?

Yes, the socket receive buffer.